# How to refactor LINQ select statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Given the following LINQ statement, can someone tell me if it is possible to refactor the select portion into an expression tree? I have not used expression tree's before and have not been able to find much information regarding Selects.. Note this is to be translated into SQL and run inside SQL Server, not in memory.

```
var results = db.Widgets
    .Select(w => new
    {
        Name = (w is x) ? "Widget A" : "Widget B"
    });
```

I would like to be able to do this..

```
var name = [INSERT REUSABLE EXPRESSION]
var somethingElse = [INSERT REUSABLE EXPRESSION]
var results = db.Widgets.Select(w => new { Name = name, SomethingElse = somethingElse });
```

Obviously the intended use is for more complex statements.

Comment: So `WidgetType` is a string? You'd like to assign a Expression to a string? Or do you want the WidgetType to be an expression.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen WidgetType is just a string. Im trying to find a way to refactor commonly used select statements in my LINQ code

Comment: As far as I know `Expression` is very similar to `delegate`, the difference is **it's used to translate the logic at client into SQL query at server, execute query there and get the result back**, so the code you wrote is some kind of very strange and it's hard to achieve, at least you have to follow the rule of passing a `delegate` or `Expression` into a method.

Comment: @KingKing I may be confusing my terms and it may be that i dont need to use an expression tree at all. But im still stuck having a lot of repeated select statements that id like to refactor.

Comment: What wrong with creating a (static) method that returns a string and call it like: `var results = db.Widgets.Select(w => new { WidgetType = WidgetTypeHelper.GetWidgetType(w) });` no expression trees involved.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen when i try something like that i get the following error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetWidgetType(Widget)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: And if you _materialize_ it first with ToArray()? `var results = db.Widgets.ToArray().Select(w => new { WidgetType = WidgetTypeHelper.GetWidgetType(w) });`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I imagine that would work just fine but due to the number of records I am running this against I need execution to happen inside SQL and not in-memory.

Comment: @Grant: Take a look at LINQKit. It may be able to do what you need, but I haven't looked into it extensively: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). It'll work as long as your method is translatable to SQL. This is essentially what a complete example might look like:

```
public static class ReusableMethods
{
    public static Expression<Func<int, Person>> GetAge()
    {
        return p => p.Age;
    }
}

var getAge = ReusableMethods.GetAge();
var ageQuery = from p in People.AsExpandable()
               select getAge.Invoke(p);
```

Note that:

1. You need to add `AsExpandable()` to your IQueryable.
2. You must assign your method to a local variable before using it (not sure about the exact reason why, but its a must).